# Connecting a Seagate 5T Backup Plus drive to a TP-Link AC1750 router

Tags: networking, router, external-hard-drive

I have already partitioned the Seagate to 2, 2 and 1 all in FAT though nothing is in stone so I can repartition. I did this because one forum said TP Link can't handle over 2TB drives. I did not go exFAT for no discernible reason I can remember.

I went to the router's settings page from my browser and the USB connect option in the router menu doesn't seem to recognize the Seagate.

I connected a 64GB flash drive and it is recognized but only 17GB and there are no files on either the Seagate nor the flash drive.

How can I get this drive to work with the router?